# Spring Webflux Server Sent Events Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I have a list of subjects that can be registered to students. A subject has a property `maxParticipants`. 
**Example:**
**Subject:** Spanish
**Max Participants:** 5

I want to update the available subject places by a Spring `Flux` with a given interval. This is no problem (every 10s i do a `select count` on the datasource to get the available places).

My question is:
How do i update the frontend being rendered with thymeleaf?
There are numerous examples using thymeleaf and spring webflux but all of them are dealing with a large list where the `@Controller` `Model` is set with a certain thymeleaf type.

I just want to update existing records.
Do i need to do this with plain javascript/jquery?
Thanks for your tips!
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use EventSource in the web page. Follow example

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-webflux-server-sent-events-example/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that out.